# How to add if then else based on mutable variables in FParsec parsers?

Tags: f#, mutable, side-effects, fparsec

I'm trying to add error recovery to an FParsec parser that consumes a comma-separated sequence in parentheses, e.g. "(a,b,c)".

I came across the following problem: Given the two inputs "()" and "(a,b,)", the first is correct in my syntax, but the second is not (since it does not end the sequence properly). While I managed to recover in the second use case and produce appropriate diagnostics there, my error recovery mechanism still produced a false positive diagnostic in the first case which I wanted to avoid.

To distinguish these two cases, my idea was to "simply check" if my sequence was actually empty when I parse the closing ")".

To accomplish this, I tried to add a mutable counter and increment it while parsing the sequence.

I came across a very strange behavior: The incrementing works, but checking if the value is zero or greater than zero does not.

After hours of debugging and trying to understand what was going wrong, I wrote a simple program to reproduce the strange behavior.

```
open FParsec

type MyClass() = 
    let mutable contextCounter = 0
    member this.Increment() =
        contextCounter <- contextCounter + 1

    member this.Reset() =
        contextCounter <- 0

    member this.GetCounter() = contextCounter

    member this.Print(s:string) =
        printf "\ncurrent value is %i, %s after checking if equals 0" contextCounter s

let x = pchar 'x'  
let y = pchar 'y' 
let z = pchar 'z'
let c = skipChar ','
let ad = MyClass()
let choicexyz (ad:MyClass) = 
    if ad.GetCounter()=0 then
        choice [x;y;z] >>= fun result -> 
            ad.Print("in if block")
            ad.Increment() 
            preturn result
    else
        z >>= fun result -> 
        ad.Print("in else block")
        ad.Increment() 
        preturn result

let parserSepBy (ad:MyClass) = 
    ad.Reset()
    sepBy (choicexyz ad) c

let inputSepBy = "x,x,y,y,z,z"
let resultSepBy = run (parserSepBy ad) inputSepBy
printf "\n%O" resultSepBy
```

This program leaves out all the unnecessary stuff like the opening and closing parentheses, error recovery, diagnostics, etc. But it reproduces what I want to demonstrate. The output is

```
current value is 0, in if block after checking if equals 0
current value is 1, in if block after checking if equals 0
current value is 2, in if block after checking if equals 0
current value is 3, in if block after checking if equals 0
current value is 4, in if block after checking if equals 0
current value is 5, in if block after checking if equals 0
Success: ['x'; 'x'; 'y'; 'y'; 'z'; 'z']
```

Why does the increment work, but checking if the value is equal to 0 doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `choicexyz` in `sepBy (choicexyz ad) c`, you create a parser function. At that point the counter is evaluated and still zero (as you just reset it). So the parser function is what you define in the `if` branch. When then later that parser function is applied by `run`, it will always be that same function and print `in if block`.

I think you have to work with user state in fparsec to do what you want to do.